# Magento 2.4.6-p2 ReservationData::__construct(): Argument #2 ($stock) must be of type int, null given - when redirecting to third party payment

Tags: magento2.4

I am getting the above error randomly when redirecting to third-party payment page after clicking on the Place Order button.

This mainly occurs when a failed payment, and when we retry the checkout again.

As of now no certain pattern for this, and the cart is getting empty when this is happening.

Please advise.

```
[2023-10-29T13:53:37.538314+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\InventoryIndexer\Model\Queue\ReservationData, Magento\InventoryIndexer\Model\Queue\ReservationData::__construct(): Argument #2 ($stock) must be of type int, null given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121 in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:131
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Invento...', Array)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Invento...', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/InventoryIndexer/Model/Queue/ReservationDataFactory.php(43): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('\\Magento\\Invent...', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-indexer/Plugin/InventorySales/EnqueueAfterPlaceReservationsForSalesEvent.php(99): Magento\InventoryIndexer\Model\Queue\ReservationDataFactory->create(Array)
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-indexer/Plugin/InventorySales/EnqueueAfterPlaceReservationsForSalesEvent.php(77): Magento\InventoryIndexer\Plugin\InventorySales\EnqueueAfterPlaceReservationsForSalesEvent->getReservationsDataObject(Object(Magento\InventorySales\Model\SalesChannel), Array)
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\InventoryIndexer\Plugin\InventorySales\EnqueueAfterPlaceReservationsForSalesEvent->afterExecute(Object(Magento\InventorySales\Model\PlaceReservationsForSalesEvent\Interceptor), NULL, Array, Object(Magento\InventorySales\Model\SalesChannel), Object(Magento\InventorySales\Model\SalesEvent))
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\InventorySales\Model\PlaceReservationsForSalesEvent\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Array, Object(Magento\InventorySales\Model\SalesChannel), Object(Magento\InventorySales\Model\SalesEvent))
#7 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/InventorySales/Model/PlaceReservationsForSalesEvent/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\InventorySales\Model\PlaceReservationsForSalesEvent\Interceptor->___callPlugins('execute', Array, Array)
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Plugin/CatalogInventory/StockManagement/ProcessBackItemQtyPlugin.php(154): Magento\InventorySales\Model\PlaceReservationsForSalesEvent\Interceptor->execute(Array, Object(Magento\InventorySales\Model\SalesChannel), Object(Magento\InventorySales\Model\SalesEvent))
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\InventorySales\Plugin\CatalogInventory\StockManagement\ProcessBackItemQtyPlugin->aroundBackItemQty(Object(Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockManagement\Interceptor), Object(Closure), '2890', '1.0000', 'NULL')
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockManagement\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('2890', '1.0000', 'NULL')
#11 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/CatalogInventory/Model/StockManagement/Interceptor.php(41): Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockManagement\Interceptor->___callPlugins('backItemQty', Array, NULL)
#12 /var/www/html/app/code/NetworkInternational/NGenius/Observer/ProductSaveAfter.php(90): Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockManagement\Interceptor->backItemQty('2890', '1.0000', 'NULL')
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(88): NetworkInternational\NGenius\Observer\ProductSaveAfter->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(74): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(NetworkInternational\NGenius\Observer\ProductSaveAfter), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(65): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#16 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('controller_acti...', Array)
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(277): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('controller_acti...', Array)
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(211): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatchPreDispatchEvents(Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(146): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor))
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(99): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(75): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/swissup/module-amp/Plugin/Framework/FrontController.php(48): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Swissup\Amp\Plugin\Framework\FrontController->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#32 /var/www/html/pub/index.php(30): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#33 {main} {"report_id":"45cb9ca5f6f0d6e3a0e5b0ff226012e3a1a7d0ff19d984f14a85f0c493c6527f","exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\\InventoryIndexer\\Model\\Queue\\ReservationData, Magento\\InventoryIndexer\\Model\\Queue\\ReservationData::__construct(): Argument #2 ($stock) must be of type int, null given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121 at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:131)"} []
```

Comment: Once the order is created, the quote will be set to inactive. Usually, an order is created before capturing the payment as we are required to send the order ID to the third-party payment. In case of failed payment, you either need to create a separate quote with the same items and create a new order or if your third-party payment allows you to repay against the same reference ID in case of failure then you can use that and skip the checkout process. If you have to do the checkout process then first option is better.